# Identifying type of RFI by waterfall

Tags: rfi

I'm trying to identify the type of RFI I'm seeing on the waterfall in the picture below.  It occurs mainly at night, every night, starting at about 6:30 p.m. and ending in the morning, and I have yet to identify the source.  It occurs within the same frequency range (around 6300 kHz to about 7200 kHz) every night.  It happens regardless whether I'm using a mag loop antenna, my 150' sky loop antenna, or my vertical.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I've been working on this for the last two months and am stumped.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying RFI just by the waterfall is not usually possible.

A more productive approach is to find the source physically, then the source will be obvious. If it's in your house, you can narrow down the source by turning off breakers and unplugging individual devices until the culprit is identified. If turning off your main breaker doesn't eliminate the noise then the source is somewhere else and can be found with a directional and portable antenna.

Answer (score 1):

Check this video of one hams quest to stop some RFI
https://youtu.be/Pwbk8yP6SIk

Comment: Hi Tom, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Thanks for posting, but we discourage one-line answers that are just links, because links rot.  Would you please edit your answer to include a summary of what happened in the video?  That way if the link does rot then the answer can still be useful.